# write hex data to file at specific address c#

Tags: c#, binary, hex

I need help to write hex data AB at adress 0x0156 in binary file in c#.
What i used BinaryWriter gives wrong data 00.

```
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(path));
bw.Write("AB");
bw.Dispose();
```

Comment: If you need to write it at address 0x156 you need to move there first using the [Seek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.seek(v=vs.110).aspx) method. You also need to write a byte value rather than a string.

Comment: and define the behavior when the "address" does not exist (file shorter than 342 bytes). Related, if the file does not exist then `File.OpenWrite(string)` will [create it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.openwrite(v=vs.110).aspx) with 0 bytes initial size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to write it at address 0x156 you need to move there first using the Seek method. You also need to write a byte value rather than a string.

```
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(path));
bw.Seek(0x156,SeekOrigin.Begin);
bw.Write((byte)0xab);
bw.Dispose();
```

If the file does not exist, or is shorter than 343 bytes, it will be padded with 0 values up to the 342nd byte.

If you want to write a number of bytes starting from a particular location you could do something like this :

```
int StartLocation = 0x202;
int EndLocation = 0x30b;
byte ValueToWrite = 0xFF;
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(path));
bw.Seek(StartLocation,SeekOrigin.Begin);
for (int CurLocation = StartLocation; CurLocation <= EndLocation; CurLocation++)
  bw.Write(ValueToWrite);
bw.Dispose();
```

Another way would be

```
int StartLocation = 0x202;
int EndLocation = 0x30b;
byte ValueToWrite = 0xFF;
byte [] ByteArray = new byte[EndLocation-StartLocation+1];
for (int i = 0; i < ByteArray.Length; i++)
  ByteArray[i] = ValueToWrite;
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(path));
bw.Seek(StartLocation,SeekOrigin.Begin);
bw.Write(ByteArray);
bw.Dispose();
```

Comment: You could either use a for loop - writing the appropriate number of bytes - each write automatically increments to the next file position - so you don't need to do a seek each time. But a better solution would be to create an array of 5 bytes initialised to 0xFF & use the [byte array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx149a0k(v=vs.110).aspx) version of the Write method =>  _"byte [] ba =  {0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff}; bw.Write(ba);"_

Comment: I have shown you the byte array technique which is the better way to go, the for loop is just basic C# (& same as C/C++) _"for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) bw.Write((byte)0xff);"_

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: i dont understand you very well i tried this for (int i = 0x010; i <= 0x011; i++) { bw.Write((byte)0xff); } but that writes ff at first 2 00,01 i want a command that will write bytes from eg 202 to 30b if you understand me –

Comment: I have updated my answer - hopefully this will help - showing both "for loop" method and byte array.